# save and clear terminal window in linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal

This is probably a dumb question that's been answered before. But, I don't know how to phrase it correctly for it to show up in the search results.

In the Linux terminal, programs like less, man, or vim take up the entire screen and display their info, then when they're closed, are replaced with the original contents of the terminal. Showing the previously run commands and such.

How do I do this?, what are the keywords associated with this action, so I can look it up.

Or if you wish, could you provide a brief explanation of the process?

Comment: You are looking for the `curses` library.

Comment: This should cover it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221317/how-to-write-full-screen-linux-console-app-script